# Running a method for infinitely in google app engine/Gwt

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am having a a method which listens continuously to a stream from a server and writes that data to datastore in google app which is later on retrieved by other methods.
How can i do that in google app engine i.e calling that method one time during the starting of app and having it running for unlimited time without affecting other things.
I am new to java world,So please help from that point of  view  also.How's that done in Java?

Answer (score 2):

Specific for the google app engine you would use a task. However, on google app engine tasks are limited to 30 seconds execution time or anything that runs on appengine, like a http request. This means you are limited in running long running tasks.
See: [http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview.html#Task_Execution)

Comment: Can you schedule many end-to-end short running tasks which can give the same result?

Comment: I think it's possible. If your task's execution nears the 30 second limit, App Engine will raise an exception which you may catch and then add a new task to the task queue. Tasks are executed in a queue so there might be some time between execution of 2 tasks.